# getting _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v' when running agent of craftassist

Tags: python, pickle, minecraft

i am trying to run https://github.com/facebookresearch/craftassist and when running the agent, I get

```
  File "./python/craftassist/craftassist_agent.py", line 27, in <module>
    import memory
  File "/root/craftassist/python/craftassist/memory.py", line 23, in <module>
    import dance
  File "/root/craftassist/python/craftassist/dance.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tasks
  File "/root/craftassist/python/craftassist/tasks.py", line 18, in <module>
    from perception import ground_height
  File "/root/craftassist/python/craftassist/perception.py", line 24, in <module>
    BLOCK_DATA = minecraft_specs.get_block_data()
  File "/root/craftassist/python/craftassist/minecraft_specs.py", line 24, in get_block_data
    _BLOCK_DATA = _pickle_load("block_images/block_data")
  File "/root/craftassist/python/craftassist/minecraft_specs.py", line 68, in _pickle_load
    return pickle.load(f)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'
```

how can I solve this issue?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook team fixed it, problem solved

Comment: This is not really an answer. Can you edit this to include the details of what you had to do to include whatever facebook "fixed"?

Comment: I dunno, link to the issue I made on GitHub: